# how to reverse the order in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, date, reverse

if i have the following data in excel.

```
Date:            Stock Price:

12/12/2012       89.90      

03/10/2012       90.88

04/12/2010       72.11

05/06/2008       76.88
```

How can I reverse both the date and the stock price? So I start from `05/06/2008` with stock price of `76.88` to `12/12/2012` with the stock price `89.90`?

Please help step by step.

So far when I tried to reverse the date solely, it only reverse year by year, so I get

```
03/10/2012 
12/12/2012
04/12/2010
05/06/2008
```

And this is not even correct, and I dont know how to reverse both date and the stock price.

I am using microsoft excel 2010 version.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show what you've tried so far that isn't working for you. This isn't really a tutorial site, and it isn't a code writing service either. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why you are not just using a simple ascending sort on the date while including the prices in the sort range. That's doable from Data/Sort on the ribbon. Are the dates strings (in which you could use the DATAVALUE function to convert them to Excel date value, which would sort the way you want them to)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As chuff indicated in the comment, all you need to do is to sort your data using Excel's sort functionality:

1. Click on a cell in your table
2. Click on *Data* tab->*Sort*
3. Set the dialog as follows: [image]

You'll end up with the sorted list:

[image]